# Простое или сложное бессоюзное предложение?

Tags: синтаксис, запятые, спп, ссп

Шли маленькие люди между больших деревьев и в грозном шуме молний, **шли они, и, качаясь, великаны-деревья скрипели и гудели сердитые песни**, а молнии летая над вершинами леса освещали его на минутку синим холодным огнем и исчезали так же быстро, как являлись, пугая людей.

Здесь 4 грамматические основы. А сколько простых предложений в составе сложного - 3 или 4? Выделенное предложение - простое с однородными членами или бессоюзное сложное? Шли они и великаны деревья скрипели... С другой стороны, часть **шли, и, качаясь** не имеет законченного смысла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сколько грамматических основ, столько и предложений - 5.

[Шли маленькие люди между больших деревьев и в грозном шуме молний], [шли они], и, [качаясь, великаны-деревья скрипели и гудели сердитые песни], а[ молнии, летая над вершинами леса, освещали его на минутку синим, холодным огнем и исчезали так же быстро, (как являлись), пугая людей].

Вы не увидели придаточное неполное предложение /как являлись/, видимо приняв за сравнительный оборот, но сравнительный оборот обычно включает существительное или другую часть речи, являющуюся второстепенным членом, а здесь глагол -сказуемое с пропуском подлежащего - молнии, они.

... и исчезали так же быстро, (как быстро они являлись), пугая людей.

Answer (score 2):

**Мне кажется, что граница между предложениями 1 и 2 в другом месте:**

(1) Шли маленькие люди между больших деревьев, (2) и в грозном шуме молний шли они, (3) и, качаясь, великаны-деревья скрипели и гудели сердитые песни, (4) а молнии, летая над вершинами леса, освещали его на минутку синим холодным огнем и исчезали так же быстро, (5) как (они) являлись, пугая людей.

Сложное предложение с сочинительной и подчинительной связью, 5 граммтических основ.

Сочинительная связь предложений 1, 2, 3, 4. Подчинительная связь между предложением 4 и 5. Однородные члены в предложениях 3 и 4.

Comment: Jasmin, это отрывок из старухи Изергиль. А там именно запятые расставлены так, как в вопросе.

Comment: Да, спасибо, Серж, я посмотрела. С автором, конечно, не поспоришь. Только вот интересно: союз И здесь связывает однородные обстоятельства? Если да, то они вроде бы на один вопрос должны отвечать, а здесь "где? при каких условиях?"Речь идет о сочетании "между больших деревьев  и в грозном шуме молний".

Comment: @ Jasmin первоначально я расставил знаки препинания так,как вы.